# How to continues the Fullscreen mode , when navigate another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullscreen

I've two html pages, i need to show it in full screen mode, i already have code for fullscreen mode, but issues is , when im click full screen mode, then click to link for traverse another page, the full screen mode was escaped, how to fix it?

i Need Follwing:

1.Fullscreen mode continues when navigate to one page to another.
2. At the same if i click normal mode its goes normal mode in all page (Vice versa..)

Following Code for fullscreen

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="fullscreen/jquery.fullsereen.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.open').click(function() {
                $('body').fullscreen();
            document.getElementById("fulls").style.cssText="display:none";
             document.getElementById("nor").style.cssText="display:show";
                return false;

            });

            $('.exit').click(function() {
                $.fullscreen.exit();
            document.getElementById("fulls").style.cssText="display:show";
            document.getElementById("nor").style.cssText="display:none";
                return false;

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Please give a suggetions.

Comment: Can you use a get parameter or a cookie?

Comment: im not using yet. i think i want to pass some value from page 1 to page2,

Comment: Could you please help to do this ,

Comment: How about the HTML? Or the CSS for `#nor` and ` #fulls`?

Comment: its just a two buttons, with id of #nor and #fulls. When click the #fulls button , page goes to fullscreen mode, in opposition of #nor.

Comment: "jquery.Fullscreen.js " is a jquery plugin get from internet., (https://github.com/kayahr/jquery-fullscreen-plugin)

Comment: have a look at cookies, that would seem to be your best option for persisting the state of the screen mode

Comment: how to set cookies and pass values to another page?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't want to use any server side techniques of sending data from page to another, you can just use this jQuery cookie plugin, It creates cookie that can be shared / accessed via different pages

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

So in the start of each page, you have to check the cookie value and set the view according to last selected value by this user